# scriptable image viewer for Windows

Tags: images, script, automation, image-viewer

What are some image viewers on Windows that can be scripted?

For example, the user opens a folder in the image viewer and he/she wants to mark some images in the folder for deletion. The user may invoke an embedded script that mark some images in a folder for deletion based on some rules regarding filename, modified date, image size, and then he may manually mark some of the rest, unmark some of the marked images, then press some button to delete all images that are marked for deletion.

Non-scriptable image viewer will fail him as soon as the rules he want to use for automatic mark for deletion gets complicated.

Comment: I would suggest you look into batch image processing instead. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/808814/search-for-images-by-has-geotag-data/905608#905608) for an example. You can customize all the properties like file name, attributes, etc. It's not exactly scripted, but the closest thing you would find IMHO.