# Search for images by "has Geotag data"

Tags: images, search, file-search, search-indexing, geotagging

I have tens of thousands of pictures that I took. Some have Geotag data in their EXIF, some don't. I want to run a search on my computer to find all images that have Geotag data. How can I accomplish this?

Using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Batch Images http://www.binarymark.com/products/batchimages/default.aspx

Step 1: Specify the folder(s) where you want to scan for images, and specify file name pattern if applies:

[image: Add images]
[image: Search for images]

Step 2: Under image properties tab, under Metadata check EXIF GPS, that way saying explicitly that you require images to have that metadata type (which is what you want)
[image: Metadata]

Step 3: Click search and wait. When the search is done images will be added to the list in the main window, which you can the either work with (process, modify, convert, etc.), or save it as a txt file for use by other programs. You can also directly copy image files from within the program.

Although the program is paid, you can accomplish this with the free trial version so you don't need to buy a license.

Disclaimer: I have the paid version and am an active user.